# how to send and receive structs through message queues?

Tags: c++, message-queue

I want to send messages in the form of structs from one process to another using POSIX message queues.

I can send and receive simple strings. I have tried to serialize the Object but therefore i would need a std::ostream or std::istream.

What is the convenient way to do that?

Comment: Do the object contain complex fields, like pointers or instances of other classes that contains pointers (like `std::string` or `std::vector`)? If not (i.e. it only contain POD members) then just sending the structure, as is, will work fine. Otherwise you might want to look into e.g. [the Boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: never needed it, but if you're IPCying between processes with different alignments, bit depths, ... the binary approach might fail if there's no magic behind the scenes which handles that

Comment: yes, the object contains complex fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [the Boost serialization library‌​](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) as recommended by Joachim Pileborg and it worked fine.